# SWITCH function in Access2007 SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using this code to edit a column in my table depending on the value in a different column, but for some reason, this code does not work!

```
UPDATE DB_Total
SET FORMAT =
SWITCH 
(Type LIKE "INT") THEN "###"
(Type LIKE "UINT") THEN "###"
(Type LIKE "DIGITAL") THEN "#"
```

What do I need to change for this code to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the proper way to do it:

```
UPDATE DB_Total 
SET FORMAT = SWITCH(
     Type Like "INT","###",
     Type Like "UINT","###",
     Type Like "DIGITAL","#");
```

Answered my own question for future reference and people that struggle with the same problem!